# underline and number for a part of a text

Tags: numbering, underline

How can we underline a part of a text which is accompanied by a number beside the text as the below figure:
[image]

Comment: For underlining see the `soul` package or the `ulem` package. For the number in the margin, I'd use `marginnote` for good placement (more precise than `\marginpar`) together with a custom counter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My comment as code. Because of `\refstepcounter` you can even label those numbers.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{duckuments}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{ulnumcolor}{HTML}{10d010}

\setul{}{.25ex}
\setulcolor{ulnumcolor}
\newcounter{ulnumcount}
\newcommand\ulnum[1]
  {\refstepcounter{ulnumcount}\marginnote{\theulnumcount}\ul{#1}}


\begin{document}
\blindduck
\ulnum{foobar}
\blindduck

\blindduck
\ulnum{bazbang}
\blindduck
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: File 'duckuments.sty' not found. \usepackege

Comment: is output!!!!!!!!

Comment: @Irreversible `duckuments` is not needed for the code to work, it is just to produce some dummy text. It is contained in the latest TeX Live and MikTeX distributions. You can leave it out and use the `\ulnum` macro in your file.

Comment: Thank you so much, is there any way to bold the number which is in the margine?

Comment: or for example change the color of the number?

Comment: @Irreversible just change the stuff in `\marginnote`'s argument to contain what you need. For example, to give it the same colour as the underline and make it bold use: `\marginnote{\textcolor{ulnumcolor}{\textbf{\theulnumcount}}}`

Comment: It is amazing and wonderful.....Thanks......

Comment: But a little question: in a two-column text when I use above code to apply an underline and a number for a text in the left column, unfortunately the number puts in the right margin. In fact, It must be in the left margin close to the underlined text.

Comment: @Irreversible you might need to ask a new question about that new problem, then ;)